# Login system using classes c++

Tags: c++, oop, authentication

Hello I try to implement a login system but I tried so many times and I still don't get it.
I have a class user and a class login, and a test function..i tried this after a tutorial, but there it was a default username and password, and only that one worked in login, but i need to have the possibility of each user's login;

```
class User{

private:

char *username;
char *password;

public:
User(){}
User(char *,char *p){...}
~User();
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, User &u);
char* getUsername(){...};
char* getPassword(){...};
};

class Loginn
{
public:
    string username;
    string password;

    Loginn()
    {
        username = "\0";
        password = "\0";
    }

    };

bool Loginn::ptlogin(User users[])
{
    int x;
    string ch_username = users[x].getUsername;
    string ch_password = users[x].getPassword;
    cout << "Enter username::\t";
    cin >> username;
    cout << "Enter password::\t";
    cin >> password;


    if ((username == ch_username)&&(password =ch_password))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}


void MainMenu(User users[]);
{
//this is from where I want to call login function, not from main()
}

void main()
{


    User u2("Jamie15","t3456");
    User u3("Chris","fgh6");

User users[2]={u2,u3};

MainMenu(users);


}
```

I want my login system to test if the username and password entered match to a user's password and username, my users are u2 and u3. Thank you!
Also, the data type from user needs to stay char, i cannot change it.

Comment: That code doesn't look like it will compile. Show the real code. Ignoring  that, `password =ch_password` ---> `password == ch_password`.

Comment: that's it..i don't know to to make it work...

Comment: Is there any chance you could research the internet for "c++ login system example" or "stackoverflow c++ login system".  There are already a plethora of similar questions.

Comment: A more robust and successful login system uses the `std::string` class (see your `User` class).  Using character arrays opens a hole in your program for buffer overflows.

Comment: The `main` function returns an `int` to the operating system.  Always.

Answer (score 1):

In your `Loginn::ptlogin` method, the index variable `x` is not initialized.

The expression:
`users[x].getUsername;`

could return anything from memory or access memory that you don't have access to; all depending on the random, uninitialized value of `x` index.

I highly recommend using `std::vector` instead of arrays.  Also, pass the index you are referring to (or at least initialize it).

**Edit 1:  The `MainMenu` function**
In order to *call* the login function, you either need to have an instance (variable) of the `Login` class or make the login function as static.

```
void MainMenu(std::vector<User>& users)
{
  Loginn instance;
  instance.ptlogin(users);
}
```

An alternative is to create the login instance in `main` and pass it to `MainMenu`:

```
void MainMenu(std::vector<User>& users,
              Loginn& instance);

int main(void)
{
  std::vector<User> users;
  Loginn instance;
  MainMenu(users, instance);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Edit 2:  A static method**
If you have a `static` method, you don't need an instance to call the method:

```
class Loginn
{
  public:
    static void ptlogin(std::vector<User>& users);
};

void MainMenu(std::vector<User>& users)
{
  Loginn::ptLogin(users);
}
```